# data is inserting in object but not updating the list group in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am inserting input data into object and that object is looped in a list element while i inserted the new item to object but the loop of list

please help me thanks in advance

and help me to reset the input field after this function is compleated

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component{

    todos = [
        {value:"hahaha", id:"01"},
        {value:"duygud", id:"02"},
        {value:"oisdpo", id:"03"}
    ]

    insertData(){
        let msg=document.getElementById('item').value;
        let item={value:msg}
        this.todos.push(item);
        this.setState(this.state);
        console.log(this.todos); 
    }

    sample(msg){
        alert(msg)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div><br /><br />
                <div class="container col-4">              
                    <input type="text" id="item" class="form-group col-12 in" name="item"   onKeyPress={(event) => {if (event.key === "Enter") {this.insertData()}}} />
                        <ul class="list-group">
                           { this.todos.map(todo => <li class="list-group-item li">{todo.value} <i class="far icon text-danger fa-times-circle float-right" onClick={()=>this.sample('hello data')}></i></li> )}

                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put `todos` into the state, i.e.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {todos: /*...*/}
}
```

and in `insertData`:

```
//...
this.setState({...this.state, todos: [...this.state.todos, item]});
```

then, the default way of `shouldComponentUpdate` will pick up the state. The slightly weired way of making this visible gives a case for using immutability and/or a state management framework; per se though, you should be able to move on

Comment: i am new to react can you please tell me the way with out putting dots

Comment: can i have anything to reset my input element when i pressed enter

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned your app is missing out on some reactjs principles (read as no state/missing constructor, mixing DOM manipulation into react, mutable state etc)

Here is a fully coded reactjs app:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        { value: "hahaha", id: "1" },
        { value: "duygud", id: "2" },
        { value: "oisdpo", id: "3" }
      ],
      item:''
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.sample = this.sample.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleButtonClick(event) {    
    if(this.state.item) {
      let newId= this.state.todos.length+1
      let newTodo = {
        value: this.state.item,
        id : (newId + '')
      }
      let newTodos =  [...this.state.todos, newTodo];    
       this.setState({
          todos: newTodos
       },() => console.log(this.state.todos));
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;    
     this.setState({
          [name]: value
       });
  }

  sample(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div className="container col-4">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="item"
            className="form-group col-12 in"
            name="item"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            value = {this.state.item}/>
          <button           
            id="add"
            className="form-group col-12 in"
            name="add"
            onClick={this.handleButtonClick}> Add </button>
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
              <li key={todo.id} className="list-group-item li">
                {todo.value}{" "}                
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/bdevapatla/pen/pKpEWV

Hope this helps!